# Tension on bolt of a seated angle

Tags: structural-engineering

Learning the basics sometimes is frustrating. Everyone uses it but no one knows where it really comes form.

On the left diagram, What is the proper name of the triangle in sketch below.
Why do we assume it to be a triangle.
What is the supporting document that allows this assumption.
Why isn't it like sketch #2 below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### These are defined by the structure itself.

Items attached to a wall experience stress at all points along the wall.  Your second diagram would only apply if the piece were supported by a point on the lower end.  Textbooks on the subject discuss it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the vertical force $F$, the length of the section of the bracket below the bolt $L$, and the distance between $F$ and the wall $D$. The triangular stress distribution is due to the very small rotation of the bracket caused by the torque of

$$T=FD$$

If we exaggerated the support's deflection under this rotation effort by orders of magnitude it would look similar to the deflection of say, a hard rubber wall under this torque. see the figure.

The stress along the Y axis

$$\sigma Y \propto Y*sin(A)$$

So as we start from the bolt compression stress starts from zero and gradually increases to $L*sin(A)$

'

[image: deflction o support]